# Using Jdk1.8 and installing openjdk 11

Tags: java, ubuntu, environment-variables

I had a working java 8 application in my windows asset until I installed jdk11 using Ubuntu package.
Now when I give java -version cmd in Ubuntu I get the openjdk 11 version:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.22.7.1 (build 11.0.22+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.22.7.1 (build 11.0.22+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

But when I try the same in cmd, I get an error unable to open:

```
java -version
Error: could not open `C:\Java\New folder\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

Is it not possible to use both as per the need?

On my company asset, I could use both(jdk 8 nd 17) changing the env variables setup but both were different applications and not from any packages like in this case.

Edit:
I was doing these changes after which jdk8 stopped working.
https://www.conduktor.io/kafka/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-windows/#Installing-Java-JDK-11-5

Comment: Are you using the same install for both Windows and Ubuntu? If yes, that's the reason why it doesn't work. If no - what does the folder `C:\Java\New folder\lib\amd64\` contain?

Comment: @Sam I am not very sure abt what you meant. for jdk 8 I installed an application setup in the directory C:\Java\jdk and jre. There is no New Folder inside Java directory. Inside the jre directory I have the lib/amd64 folders.
And for the openjdk 11, I installed it using powershell cmd

wget -O- https://apt.corretto.aws/corretto.key | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://apt.corretto.aws stable main'
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y java-11-amazon-corretto-jdk

Comment: What do you mean by "in cmd"? Did you call the first `java -version` in a terminal app within Ubuntu GUI environment? If so, where/how did you call `java -version` in your second example?

Comment: By the way, a tip: https://sdkman.io/